# How to add request.user to manytomanyfield for team members in django?

Tags: python, django, database

I was trying to create a custom team model having a manytomanyfield for team members, now i have a form that allows users to create their own team(s), but i dont understand how i can add request.user to the members of the team. Below are the codes:

models.py

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Member')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Team: {self.name} created on {self.created_at}\nMember(s): {self.members}"


class Member(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
```

forms.py

```
class TeamRegistrationForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ["name", "description"]
```

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def teamregister(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TeamRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            form.instance.members.add(request.user) # doesn't work :[
            print(form.save())
            messages.success(request, "Your team has been successfully registered!")
            return redirect("dashboard")
    else:
        form = TeamRegistrationForm()

    return render(request, "users/team.html", {"form": form})
```

I tried to use `form.instance.members.add(request.user)` to add the logged in user to the member of the team but it didn't work. Please help :[

Comment: What is not working? What errors does it raise?

Comment: in django shell when i printed our the query set it printed that there were no members in the created team
`<QuerySet [<Team: Team: volt's squad created on 2020-08-06 14:58:53.398269+00:00
Member(s): auth.User.None>]>`
while what i wanted was that the current logged in user shouldve showed up in the members

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is *added* to the relation, but you do not print the items in the relation. You print the manager. Indeed, you write `{self.members}`, and that is the manager, you should rewrite this to `{self.manager.all()}`. A `Manager` will, unless you implement it otherwise return `ModelName.None`:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    # …

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Team: {self.name} created on {self.created_at}\nMember(s): {self.members.all()}'
```

Comment: omg thank you a lot, you just saved me. thank you very much edit: can you also tell how can i display the team names on the user profile page, i tried ```{% for team in user.member.team %}
    {{ team.name }}
{% endfor %} ```
@WillemVanOnsem

Comment: `{% for team in user.member.all %} {{ team.name }}{ endfor %}`.

Comment: it is showing an error now `*MultipleObjectsReturned at /dashboard/* get() returned more than one Member -- it returned 2!` @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @Volt: that means you somewhere have used a `.get`, instead of a `.filter` for example. You should inspect the traceback...

Comment: I will try my best to find the error, and edit this comment with the solution. Thank you for helping me